# In linq dynamic order by throw error invalid operation in C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dynamic

**invalid operation**

```
public static List<T> Sort<T>(SortingDto? request, List<T> entity)
    {
        if (request != null && request.SortKey != null)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            string? key = request.SortKey;
            var keyInfo = type.GetProperty(key);
            entity = request.SortOrder.ToLower() == Constants.Assending
                ? entity.OrderBy(x => keyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList()
                : entity.OrderByDescending(x => keyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
        }
        return entity;
    }
```

T'((System.RuntimeType)type).DeclaringMethod' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I always getting keyinfo as 'Null' due to that unable to apply order by on any property. That was because of difference in naming convention between property(Table parameter) and key(that I paased).

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of exception due to naming convention of property and key Name. That can we avoid by using following:

```
PropertyInfo? keyinfo = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == key.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();
```